# Использование однородных и неоднородных определений вперемешку

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

1. Могут ли такие ситуации возникнуть (однородные и неоднородные определения в одном ряду)?
2. Если да, то как при этом расставлять запятые? Вот например, если будет что-то подобное: *однородное, неоднородное неоднородное, однородное.* (Если пример некорректный, можно рассмотреть любой другой случай, подходящий под интересующий меня принцип.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При сочетании  однородных и неоднородных определений отношения между ними определяются по обычным правилам:

1) Два однородных (сходные или сближенные признаки) и неоднородное определение

Она несла ***отвратительные, тревожные*** жёлтые цветы (М. Булгаков).

Петя был теперь ***красивый, румяный*** пятнадцатилетний мальчик (Л. Толстой).

Стояли ***жаркие, безветренные*** июльские дни (Л. Толстой).

2) Два неоднородных и два однородных определения

Перед ним был типичный ***добрый, простодушный*** русский человек.

Пример "однородное, неоднородное, неоднородное, однородное" **некорректен**, однородные определения всегда располагаются  рядом.